# nginx static images fallback

Tags: nginx, static-files, fallback

i use nginx 1.6.2 to serve static images from a folder. I need to serve the requested file if exists or fallback to a default image.

i had this location block

```
location /test/img/ {
    rewrite  ^/test/img/(.*)  /$1 break;
    root   /path/to/folder/images;
    try_files $uri /default.jpg;
}
```

The "/path/to/folder/images" folder contains 2 files: image1.jpg and default.jpg.
If I request an existing image all works correctly. For example, if I do a GET on this url

```
<host_name>/test/img/image1.jpg
```

I can see the correct image but if I search an unknown image I had a 404 response.
From the error.log file I can see this error:

```
[error] 18128#0: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/default.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Why nginx searchs default.jpg in that folder? I expected to search that file in the root of the location block. I tried without success to use the absolute path.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`try_files` last parameter leads to internal redirect. So nginx acts as if it was called with URI `/default.jpg` and will not go to `/test/img/`.

But you problem could be fixed easily with `alias` directive without rewrites.

```
location /test/img/ {
    alias /path/to/folder/images/;
    try_files $uri default.jpg =404;
}
```

#### testing config

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8888;
    location /test/img/ {
        alias /var/tmp/site/images/;
        try_files $uri default.jpg =404;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    }
}
```

Requests:

```
curl localhost:8888/test/img/image.jpg
curl localhost:8888/test/img/non-existent.jpg
```

debug log:

```
... for image.jpg
2015/06/05 12:16:53 [debug] 4299#0: *5 try files phase: 14
2015/06/05 12:16:53 [debug] 4299#0: *5 http script var: "/test/img/image.jpg"
2015/06/05 12:16:53 [debug] 4299#0: *5 trying to use file: "image.jpg" "/var/tmp/site/images/image.jpg"
2015/06/05 12:16:53 [debug] 4299#0: *5 try file uri: "/test/img/image.jpg"

... for non-existent.jpg
2015/06/05 12:15:50 [debug] 4299#0: *4 try files phase: 14
2015/06/05 12:15:50 [debug] 4299#0: *4 http script var: "/test/img/non-existent.jpg"
2015/06/05 12:15:50 [debug] 4299#0: *4 trying to use file: "non-existent.jpg" "/var/tmp/site/images/non-existent.jpg"
2015/06/05 12:15:50 [debug] 4299#0: *4 trying to use file: "default.jpg" "/var/tmp/site/images/default.jpg"
2015/06/05 12:15:50 [debug] 4299#0: *4 try file uri: "/test/img/default.jpg"
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it doesn't works. If I replace `default.jpg` with `/default.jpg` it works instead. Is this correct?

Comment: Thats weird. I've checked with my nginx.

Comment: ok, you're right...I didn't add trail slash to the alias. Yesterday I posted the solution using root and rewrite...but your answer is more elegant, objectively...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
If none of the files were found in the root folder nginx does a redirect to the url corresponding to the last parameter of the try_files directive.
So the correct block is

```
location /test/img/ {
    rewrite  ^/test/img/(.*)  /$1 break;
    root   /path/to/folder/images;
    try_files $uri /test/img/default.jpg;
}
```